# Rayleigh-Benard Convection

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, heat, convection

I found this nice [paper](http://cadcam.eng.sunysb.edu/~purwar/MEC501/report.pdf) about RB convection. However I am confused by what is going on page 6. In particular why we are suddenly using Helmholtz equation to find spatially periodic solutions. Aren't we working with convection, so why are we looking at it from a wave like point of view? Or maybe I'm just missing the point all together.

Furthermore I would like to run a quick experiment to collect data. I was planning on using a heating place, a small glass tube filled with olive oil and a thermometer. Any tips? Suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? If you can get your hands on a copy of any of Drazin's books (http://tinyurl.com/d22r476 or http://tinyurl.com/cxr5hq6) there is a good and detailed treatment of the maths involved. Not sure what you expect to find through a statistical thermal dynamics lens...

Comment: Alrighty sorry for the vague question. Now I am looking for information about why the RB convection is still being studied, a qualitative description of the process, which is backed up by a mathematical explanation. Also a mathematical explanation of where the critical Rayleigh number comes from would be nice. And on the side: how can I create an at home experiment to convince myself of the convection cells. @Qmechanic thanks for the edit!

Comment: **To add to my answer:** A layer of oil being heated on a non-stick pan shows the formation of these Benard  cells. Be careful.. I think it would be safer to use canola/vegetable oils instead of olive oil since olive oil smokes in a shorter period of time.

Comment: Your paper link is broke. Please write out the title and author of the paper so that others can find it even when the link disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it's not a little too late for this answer!!!

**Why are we looking at this from a "wave-point-of-view"**

Rayleigh's experiments were on *spermacetti* (whale oil) in a cylindrical container with an aspect ratio of depth to radius $h_0/r\lt\lt 1$. This can be treated as a **membrane** with a certain stiffness. Hence, it is common to find a **wave** . The instabilities you see in RB/MB convection are called short wavelength instabilities and these wavelengths can be calculated using linear/non-linear stability analysis and can be faithfully captured with *well controlled* experiments.

**Short note on (non)linear stability analysis**

In case you aren't aware of what this is. It is simply perturbing a system with a wave with a disturbance of the form $A \sin (k x)$ and with some clever maxima/minima differential calculus and algebra, figuring out the most destructive wavelength that emerges.

($A$ is the amplitude of the wave and is generally $0.01 h_0$, $k$ is the 
wavenumber $k = 2 \pi x/L$ and $L$ is the domain size).

**Some useful references/papers**

Besides [Killercam's reference to Drazin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/45778/7285), if you are really interested in RB or MB (Marangoni Benard) convection, I would suggest that you read [Rayleigh's 1916 paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/Rayleigh1916a.pdf) and [Thomson's 1855 paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/Thomson1855a.pdf) in addition to [Kundu's textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121782530) , particularly **chapter 12**.

**Running experiments with olive oil**

As for running experiments with olive oil in a cylinder: be careful; the dimensions of the cylinder (aspect ratio) can change the structures from the hexagonal RB/MB cells to perhaps a [Rayleigh-Taylor *type* instability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Taylor_instability).

**Extra fun stuff**

If you find that your interest is roused by RB/MB convection, eventually you look at *long wave instabilities* that affect liquid film.

**References**

Thomson, J. *On certain curious motions observable at the surfaces of wine and other alcoholic liquors* **Phil. Mag. Ser.**, 1855, 10, 330-333

Rayleigh *On convective currents in a horizontal layer of fluid when the higher temperature is on the under side*. **Philo. Mag. Series**, 1916, 32, 529-546

Comment: Dropbox links now dead.